# sql "group by" same PersonID, different PersonNames. Eliminate duplicates

Tags: sql, group-by, unique, distinct

I have a (rather dirty) datasource (excel) that looks like this:

**ID   | Name | Subject | Grade**
123 | Smith, Joe R. | MATH | 2.0
123 | Smith, Joe Rodriguez | FRENCH | 3.0
234 | Doe, Mary Jane D.| BIOLOGY | 2.5
234 | Doe, Mary Jane Dawson| CHEMISTRY | 2.5
234 | Doe, Mary Jane | FRENCH | 3.5

My application's output should look like this:

```
Smith, Joe R.
123

MATH | 2.0
FRENCH | 3.0
```

So basically I want to do query (just for the ID/Person parent 'container') something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name FROM MyTable<br/>
```

or

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID
```

Of course both of the above are invalid and won't work.
I would like to 'combine' the same ID's and ignore/truncate the other records with the same ID/different Name (because we all know they're the same person since ID is our identifier and clearly it's just a typo/dirty data).
Can this be done by a single **SELECT** query?

Comment: There are <b? and <br> tags in your question are they part of the input/output or an attempt at formatting the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really care which value shows up in the name field, use [`MAX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) or [`MIN()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx):

```
SELECT    ID,
          MAX(Name) AS Name
FROM      [YourTable]
GROUP BY  ID
```

Here's a working example to play with: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/116699/

Comment: Thank you. Worked. I forgot I needed to ORDER BY Name. I just searched around and found out I can actually use "ORDER BY 2" which is supposed to be a deprecated syntax (works though)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the MIN or MAX Value of Name

```
SELECT ID, Max(Name)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, T.Subject, T.Grade
FROM (SELECT ID, MIN(NAME) AS NAME
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY ID) A
LEFT JOIN MyTable T on A.ID = T.ID
```

Will give you something like

```
123    Smith, Joe R.     Math      2.0
123    Smith, Joe R.     FRENCH    3.0
234    Doe, Mary Jane    BIOLOGY   2.5
234    Doe, Mary Jane    CHEMISTRY 2.5
234    Doe, Mary Jane    FRENCH    3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which name you keep, you can use a `MAX()` or `MIN()` aggregate to pick just one name:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Name) as Name 
FROM MyTable GROUP BY ID
```